# Tomcat6 - Any difference in datasource when run as standalone app and as service?

Tags: windows, jdbc, tomcat6

I have been running tomcat 6 as a standalone app and with the datasource specified via the 'Data Sources' tool in Control Panel> Admininstrative Tools.

Now today, I tried to install tomcat as a service, so that it will automatically start when the pc starts up.

However it fails to recognize the datasource anymore. The same data source works when I restart tomcat from the command prompt.

The following is the stacktrace

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ([Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1225)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    com.qc.helpers.connection.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:38)
    com.qc.main.servlets.TableView.init(TableView.java:47)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using a ODBC datasource. Most likely you created a User DSN instead of a System DSN. If TomCat runs as a service, then Java is unable to access ODBC datasources defined for your normal user account. If you define it as a System DSN then it should have access.

BTW: I would suggest to not use the JDBC/ODBC bridge if possible, but to use the actual JDBC driver for your database.

Comment: i had figured it out about an hour after i posted this question... anyway, you are correct.. it was the system DSN vs user DSN problem..